# jQuery hide text, display on hover?

Tags: jquery, hover, displayobject

Hopefully just a quick question :)

I'm trying to write little jQuery that will help do this:

- text displayed on page: CA
- text displayed when mouse hovers: CALIFORNIA

I've managed to do this the wrong way round unfortunately, I know I need to use the .hide() function but I just can't figure out how to use it. Sorry I'm pretty new to jQuery and just trying to get my head round it.

Here's a jfiddle I made [link](http://jsfiddle.net/liamtarpey/UttAa/), preferably the text would slide in from the right. I've tried using a span but it seemed to work better having p tags in different divs. I understand that I'll need to put the HTML all on one line to get rid of the little space between CA and LIFORNIA. could anyone possibly please assist?

HTML:

```
<div class="state">
     <p>CA</p>
</div>
<div class="state-full">
     <p>LIFORNIA</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.state, .state-full {
     display: inline-block;
     cursor: pointer;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.state').hover(function() {
     $('.state-full').slideToggle(100, 'linear');
     $('.state-full').display(100, 'linear');
});
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code you had would work fine, you just need to modify your HTML and CSS a little to make it more semantic. Try this:

```
<div class="state">      
    <span>CA</span>
    <span class="state-full">LIFORNIA</span>
</div>
```

```css
.state, .state-full { cursor: pointer; }
.state-full { display: none; }
.state span { float: left; }
```

```js
$('.state').hover(function() {
    $('.state-full', this).slideToggle(100, 'linear').display(100, 'linear');
});
```

Note that I added a context to the selector as I assume you're going to have more than one of these on the page.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WP8ca/1/)

Comment: Many thanks guys, much appreciated. they both work great but I went with @Rory's answer in the end as it means I can do multiple 'state' divs without having to repeat the jquery over and over. I'm sure they'll both come in handy though! :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.state').mouseenter(function () {
            $(this).html("CALIFORNIA");
        });
        $('.state').mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).html("CA");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope it helps :)